# Paypal: trying to pass an amount with a Donation button

Tags: paypal, donations, urlvariables

I have a Donate button set up for the user to enter the donation amount. I am trying to send an amount with the button. I can enter amount=1.00 in the Add Advanced Variables in the button setup - that works fine. However, I have had no success sending the amount as part of the URL. I have added the following line to the PayPal button form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.99" />
```

but the amount field is blank when I get to PayPal. Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't believe you can. Here's a discussion about it: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/Cannot-pass-amount-from-my-site-to-paypal-using-the-paypal/td-p/330950.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like Paypal is pretty buggy in this regard.  At least I wasn't losing my mind.

Comment: Whoa, hold on. "It's not a bug, it's a feature!". I will clarify in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you're creating a so called 'hosted button' (that is, a button where the button details are stored on the PayPal side), then the 'amount' POST parameter is ignored for requests to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.
This is a security feature to prevent people from being able to manipulate the `amount` passed to PayPal for checkout.

You can identify whether you're using a hosted button by the following data;
Hosted buttons will have a value for `cmd` of `_s-xclick` and include the `hosted_button_id` parameter.

If this is the case, you cannot update the amount by passing in an extra `amount` POST parameter.

However, because you're dealing with donations and the amount is flexible by definition, you don't in fact need a 'hosted button'. 
In the button creation form, turn off 'Host button with PayPal', or write your own  to point to PayPal.
If you do this, you *can* set the amount via the `amount` POST parameter.

For example, the below works fine;

```
<form method="POST" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<label for="amount">Amount: </label><input type="text" name="amount" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay with PayPal">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the post, it cleared this issue up for me as well. One question: what did you mean by "write your own to point to PayPal"? I just want to be crystal clear about everything before I put a donate button up on my website. Also, to make sure there's a layer of security, should I use the Encrypted Website Payments feature if I'm not using a hosted button?

Comment: You can create buttons via PayPal's 'Button Manager', or simply write the `<form>` element yourself. Either one is fine for donations. As for security; the security is generally intended to secure the amount paid and prevent anyone from tampering with that. That doesn't apply with a donation button (precisely because you want to allow people to modify the amount), so Encrypted Website Payments is not necessary for you.

Comment: This is not enough - you have to provide **`business`** and **`item_name`**. `currency_code` is also a good idea. See **[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111009112933/https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)** for more details.

Answer (score 9):

Robert's solution is on the right track, however a non-hosted PayPal form will not work without the hidden "business" field (which should have a value of the email address associated with your PayPal account.)

Other fields should be included for thoroughness:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail@here.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation Description">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
```

Comment: PayPal also states you can also put your merchant ID in place of email for the business field. This helps avoid spammers from picking up your email address.

Comment: If you want donors to be able to set up recurring donations, the amount field must be zero. If you specify any non-zero value, PayPal does not present donors with the option to set up recurring donations, and instead assumes the donor is making a one-time donation of the specified amount.