# How to add specific amount in PayPal Donation

Tags: php, html, paypal

I'm trying to add a `donation page` with `paypal` integration. It works perfectly fine. But what I want to add is to first sign the form from my site and then send it to `paypal` as well as the selected amount of donation. I've also trid to put this code `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">` as per my research. But it's still not working. Please see my code below for your review/reference.

**Code**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="QWEVB36VTJYEG">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="88.00">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

**The result would be just like this: (Blank Value) (The value must be 88.00)**
[image]

Comment: can you show your demo link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, **donations on Paypal can't be restricted to one single value**. The `amount` input is ignored, to be sure that people who will donate are not being manipulated and forced to pay a price they did not choose.

However, if you want to propose some fixed prices, here is a [Paypal Community code](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments-Archive/Paypal-Donation-Fixed-Amounts-and-also-option-to-put-their-own/td-p/845741) which will help you doing that.

**EDIT:** Here is a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026250/paypal-trying-to-pass-an-amount-with-a-donation-button) which is pretty clear and confirms my thoughts.

Comment: Great links men.